Azure B2C: MFA With Email. Field Blank
User signs in with MFA using email with no issues. Then user clicks a link to the application again after a while within the same browser but in another tab. MFA email verification screen comes up but with email address field blank. Closing the browser or opening incognito window, the issue goes away. What gives? Thanks!


Could you include more details like code your tried and errors if any?

Found the issue, thank you. Here are 2 things I did that resolved the issue for me.
1. Added an SM-AAD Technical Profile in the TrustFrameworkExtensions file to persist readOnlyEmail as below

    <TechnicalProfile Id="SM-AAD">
      <PersistedClaims>
       <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="readOnlyEmail" />
      </PersistedClaims>
    </TehcnicalProfile>


In the EmailVerifyOnSignIn technical profile, replaced the Session Management profile SM-MFA with SM-AAD.

